# Add a click to each array item

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

So my problem is that I would like the script to click on each class after it simply logged it in the console.

I've tried adding some .click() method after a few pieces of the code but no luck.

Here is the code below

```
var array = ['.button.color.color-41d841', '.button.color.color-dc0000', '.button.color.color-1e00e9', '.button.color.color-ff6f00'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
array.forEach(function(el, index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(el);
  }, index * interval);
});
console.log('Loop finished.');
```

It just prints the element's class.

**Solved**

```
var array = ['.button.color.color-41d841', '.button.color.color-dc0000', '.button.color.color-1e00e9', '.button.color.color-ff6f00'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
array.forEach(function(el, index) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(el);
    $(el).click()
  }, index * interval);
});
console.log('Loop finished.');
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try this, you need to find the element and click on it

```
var array = ['.button.color.color-41d841', '.button.color.color-dc0000', '.button.color.color-1e00e9', '.button.color.color-ff6f00'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
array.forEach(function (el, index) {
setTimeout(function () {
console.log(el);
document.querySelector(el).click()
}, index * interval);
});
```

Comment: What if the class of the button is the same name. So there are multiple buttons with this class name.

Comment: Couldn't I use something like '.button.color[0]'

Answer (score 0):

You need to call below script.

> $(document).on('click',el,function(){});

because you are binding click event dynamically

```
 var array = ['.label-key', '.button.color.color-dc0000', '.button.color.color-1e00e9', '.button.color.color-ff6f00'];
var interval = 1000; // how much time should the delay between two iterations be (in milliseconds)?
array.forEach(function (el, index) {
$(document).on('click',el,function(){}); 
setTimeout(function () {
console.log(el);
}, index * interval);
});
console.log('Loop finished.');
```